# Body missing from first email in list sent using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email

I'm working on a way to send emails to a list of recipients. All emails should contain the same body, but with unique attachments. The code I'm using successfully retrieves the addresses from column N, and inserts attachments based on paths in corresponding rows in columns O:AZ.

The issue I'm encountering is that the first email created using the code has no body. The recipient and attachments are correct, but the email itself is empty. All other emails created show the body correctly. I have very little experience with VBA, and cannot find what's causing the issue.

Any help regarding the code and possible issues would be appreciated! Please let me know if you need more details regarding the code or data.

```
Sub create_emails()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim strobody As String


With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'email addresses located in Sheet2, column N


    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("O1:AZ1") 'File paths stored in corresponding rows, columns 0:AZ

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.xxx"
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "test subject"
            .Body = strbody
            strbody = "Test text"

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Display  'Or use .Display / .Send
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I guess `strbody = "Test text"` should be above `.Body = strbody`

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but you also have typo in `Dim strobody As String`. Use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting strbody after you're using it, so the first time it's used it's empty.

Change:

```
 With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.xxx"
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = "test subject"
        .Body = strbody
        strbody = "Test text"
```

To:

```
 With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxx@xxx.xxx"
        .To = cell.Value
        .Subject = "test subject"
        strbody = "Test text"
        .Body = strbody
```

And also, if you had `Option Explicit` set, you'd notice that your declaration for `strbody` is mistyped to `strobody`.